# How to view a plist file correctly in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, plist

Currently my plist is displayed like this.

How do I get my plist file to be viewed like the bottom image? - A table view?

Thanks

[image: Currently my plist file is displaying like this.]

[image: I what this type of view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click -> Open as -> Property List.

[image]

Comment: Man, you were fast. I will delete my Answer as you have added a nice screen grab. Thanks

Comment: Don't worry I had the same problem in another project. I suggest you to check your question as answered if it's the case. (=